# Sticky footer to bottom when body height 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I like to create my styles based on the height of the window and typically do that by creating html and body to be height 100%

```
html, body{
   min-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Then I can style the heights of remaining elements based on that as shown in the jsfiddle below. Problem is, I want my footer to stick to the bottom which works great for pages that don't go beyond the window height, but if they do the footer is fixed there. How can I fix it such that I still use the html,body height of 100% and still get the footer to stick to bottom always. *Note: I have done the wrapper way of

```
#wrapper{
  min-height:100%;
}
```

and that didn't work too well cause the children elements' height doesn't work well.

http://jsfiddle.net/mmahalwy/m4AjL/

Suggestions?

---

**Edit:**
Got it solved this way:
http://jsfiddle.net/mmahalwy/7wqqF/

Thanks everyone!

Comment: @nFinIt_loop doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/mmahalwy/fY248/

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the problem ,**

You are using 2 css styles tag of 100% height each named class=block if you just made a main div with a height of 100% and all other div inside it everything will work fine .

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <container>
        <div class="block">
             <h1>Content</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="block">
             <h1>Content</h1>

        </div>
    </container>
    <footer>I am a footer</footer>
</body>

html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
container {
    background: grey;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.block {
    height: auto;
}
footer {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No it just lets the footer stick to the bottom. I want it to be at the very bottom of the document not the window

Comment: If you want it at the bottom of the document, isn't that just a regular footer?

Comment: @4m1r doesn't solve the problem of me wanting to style block class by height. So having it `height: 100%` doesn't work

Comment: height: auto in your inner blocks is the way to go.  I don't think you can have two inner blocks with 100% without breaking the container.  If you want to ensure that they grow to the height of the window, you will likely need to query window.height and apply that value / 2 to the two inner blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer might depend on what type of browser compatibility you need.

IMHO, the modern way to accomplish this is to use CSS3 flexbox, see this [useful guide from css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

The code is in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4AjL/24/.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block">
            <h1>Content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <h1>Content</h1>
        </div>
    <footer>I am a footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.block{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
footer{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    flex: none;
}
.container{
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: hasn't entirely solved it considering the content div isn't taking up the 100% of the body

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for is a sticky footer. I updated the JS Fiddle, is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/m4AjL/24/

Comment: Nope. I need it such that whether it is shorter than 100% or over 100% the footer is always at the bottom.